# Attempt at constructive proof of compactness of [0,1], does this use LEM? Does a constructive proof exist?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

Suppose I start a proof off with "Let $U_x$ be an open cover of $[0,1]$. Either $[0,1] \in U_x$ or $[0,1] \notin U_x$." Am I using the Law of the Excluded Middle here, or is this fact somehow evident without that assumption?

Also, does a constructive proof (interpreted loosely) of the compactness of $[0,1]$ exist? Is the standard proof constructive in any sense? Asked another way, is there an algorithm (again, interpreted loosely) that takes an open cover of $[0,1]$ and returns a finite open cover?

Comment: Yes, you are using the Law. What exactly do you mean by "a constructive proof" and why do you think that the Law of the Excluded Middle makes a proof non-constructive? I mean, what's non-constructive about checking whether an element is in a set and deciding upon that?

Comment: @freakish Because Andrej Bauer said so. But seriously, I guess my reason is because it doesn't hold in every topos. But on the other hand, your question makes me realize I don't understand why LEM can't be used in proves that are constructive in the sense that they provide an algorithm for obtaining the existence of any object promised by the proof. So feel free to interpret "constructive" somewhat loosely in your answer, even if it involves explaining how the standard proof is in some sense "constructive."

Comment: @freakish I missed your edit when I was typing my response. We are thinking along the same lines. I know I've heard that constructivists can use LEM when they've demonstrated that the property they are talking about is of the kind that is susceptible to LEM (not that I really know what that means).

Comment: I have some intuition but this is beyond my level of formal understanding unfortunately. I'm very interested in an answer though.

Comment: [This](http://www.ben-sherman.net/aux/cantor-compact.pdf) PDF suggests to me that LEM is very important for compactness. You might find it illuminating.

Comment: Expanding a bit on Cameron Williams' comment, usually in constructive math traditional notions have to be reformulated to be able to prove analogues of traditional theorems. In some cases this can be done by carefully picking from classically equivalent but constructively non-equivalent definitions. Typically, you'll need to do a much deeper reformulation and/or prove weaker theorems.

Comment: More oriented toward your question, equality of real numbers is usually not considered constructively decidable. That is, there can be a real number $x$ such that neither $x=1$ nor $x\neq 1$ is (constructively) provable. So assuming you are allowing intervals with arbitrary real endpoints and you are using a classical conception of an interval and open cover, then being able to decide $[0,1]\in U_x$ would mean being able to decide $x=1$ because $U_x$ might be $\{[0,x],[0.5,1]\}$ say.

Comment: As a Brouwerian weak counter-example, imagine $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)2^{-i}$ where $f(i)=1$ if $2i$ is the sum of two primes, and otherwise $0$. Being able to decide $x=1$ means knowing whether Goldbach's conjecture is true or not. We can construct [even stronger counter-examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2328059/305738).

Answer (score 2):

There is no constructive proof of the compactness of the interval of (Cauchy or Dedekind) real numbers [0, 1]. In particular it is not compact for computable real numbers. This is because there are bounded computable sequences of computable real numbers which do not converge to a computable real number.

You are using decidability whenever you say something of the form either p or not p. It's good that you've made it explicit. The law of excluded middle is used to show this for all propositions. There is no reason to expect that membership in this way is decidable (and it in general is not). So yes, you are using LEM here since that fact is neither always true nor self-evident.